# "helm-documentation"? (search docstrings like apropos-documentation but with helm)

Tags: helm, help, doc-strings

I just started using helm-apropos.  It's great!

Is there a helm equivalent for `apropos-documentation` or alternatively does `helm-apropos` have sources already available to narrow over docstrings?

Comment: If you are not limited to Helm, [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) provides [commands that do what you are request](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions#icicle-doc). `icicle-doc`, `icicle-fundoc`, and `icicle-vardoc`. You can match incrementally against doc strings. And you can also match at the same time against the function or variable name, if you want.